# Django Admin Inline FileField link to open in new tab

Tags: django, django-models, upload, django-templates

I have fieldfields in an inline in Django Admin.   The link to the file works fine and the uploaded file is shown in browser. Now i want to make the link open in a new tab. I imagine the quickest way is to insert a target="_blank" into the html, but there seems to be no template for it - maybe it's generated by python code. Can you please help me pinpoint where to inject?

models.py:

```
class Anhang(models.Model):
   antrag = models.ForeignKey(Antrag)
   upload = models.FileField(upload_to=subfolderpath)
```

admin.py:

```
class AnhangInline(admin.TabularInline):
   model = Anhang
   extra = 0
   show_change_link = False
```

In Admin:

[image]

Thank you very much.

**Solution, thanks to @JulienS:**
1. Override the template in your app:
    django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/widgets/clearable_file_input.html
2. Insert in template:
    `<a target="_blank" href="{{ widget.value.url }}">`

Comment: perhaps you need to share some codes?

Comment: @houzayfarifai done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you find a widget to URL on this  `django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\widgets` where you instal your django.

Comment: Yes, I look through it, I guess "clearable_file_input.html" is the correct one, and there the widget.value.url. But where is it generated?

Comment: Ah, my fault, ofc this is the solution. I just override the template and add "target="_blank". Works!

Comment: at your service