# Overwrite a Django Material Admin template and keep it inside Project Folder

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I'm working with Django Material Admin framework. I want to overwrite a template(example: clearable_file_input.html) and place the overwritten template in the project folder to get the updated functionality of the template while running the project.
Where do I need to place that updated template inside the project?
What are all the changes (if there is any like updating settings.py file) that I need to do for automatically fetching the updated template but not the original template?

Example Scenario: I want to update the functionality of opening a link (of TabularInline Model) when it's clicked. I want to open the link in another tab when it's clicked. So, I got to know that I need to update the clearable_file_input.html and I successfully updated that. Now I need to figure out where do I need to place this file inside my project to get the updated functionality.
I don't want to update the original template present in the path: "./local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/material/admin/templates/admin/widgets/clearable_file_input.html"
I want to place the updated template in project so that while running the project, the updated template is taken rather than the original template present in the previously specified path.

What do I need to do for this functionality to work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the template as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52296610/django-admin-inline-filefield-link-to-open-in-new-tab) but in my case, I had to do three more additional step which was to use TemplateSettings renderer instead of the default one.

Step1: You need to add the following line in your django's settings.py

```
FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting'
```

Step2: add the following to your DIRS list in TEMPLATES config

```
django.__path__[0] + '/forms/templates'
```

Step3: add `'django.forms'` in your installed apps.

That'll do the trick!